# Can't changing an xml value with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

This is my XML-file:

```
<todos>
  <todo>
    <titel>sasd</titel>
    <erstellt>2012-04-30 17:19:21</erstellt>
    <erledigen_bis>2012-05-03</erledigen_bis>
    <erledigt>Nein</erledigt>
    <thingstodo>sffsdfdf</thingstodo>
  </todo>
</todos>
```

Now I want to change the value inside of the `<erledigt>` tag to 'Ja'.

I tried this with the following code:

```
<?php
$filename = 'xml/todos.xml';

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('xml/todos.xml');

$todos = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('todo');         

foreach ($todos as $todo) {

    $titel = $todo->getElementsByTagName('titel');
    $actualTitel = $titel->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $paramTitel = $_GET["titel"];

    $erstellt = $todo->getElementsByTagName('erstellt');    
    $actualTimestamp = $erstellt->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $paramTimestamp = $_GET["timestamp"];

    if ($paramTitel == $actualTitel && $paramTimestamp == $actualTimestamp) {

        $todo->erledigt= 'Ja';

    }
}

$xmlDoc->save($filename);

header('Location: todo.php');
?>
```

Please help me, I searched for about 5 hours on the web and couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$todo->erledigt` doesn't work in DOMDocument, only SimpleXML can do that.  You need to use `getElementsByTagName` again.

You also need to use `nodeValue` to get/set the value of the element.

```
if ($paramTitel == $actualTitel && $paramTimestamp == $actualTimestamp) {
    $todo->getElementsByTagName('erledigt')->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Ja';
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/xJbQmO2u

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me from a sleepless night!

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the `<erledigt>` element by using DOM methods and properties to access it. It looks like you're confusing it with SimpleXML.

```
$todo->getElementsByTagName('erledigt')->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Ja';
```

---

If you do want to take a look at using SimpleXML, then your whole code could look something like.

```
<?php

$paramTitel = $_GET["titel"];
$paramTimestamp = $_GET["timestamp"];

$todos = simplexml_load_file('xml/todos.xml');
foreach ($todos->todo as $todo) {
    if ($paramTitel == (string) $todo->titel 
     && $paramTimestamp == (string) $todo->erstellt
    ) {
        $todo->erledigt = 'Ja';
    }
}

$todos->asXML($filename); // Where does $filename come from?

header('Location: todo.php');

?>
```

---

Reading:

- [SimpleXML usage and examples](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic)
- [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()](http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagname)
- [DOMNodeList::item()](http://php.net/domnodelist.item)
- [DOMNode::nodeValue](http://php.net/class.domnode#domnode.props.nodevalue)

Comment: Before the copy and paste I wanted to right the value instead of the $filename, but I had only deleted it and hadn't edit it later, sorry if I confused you.
The SimpleXML-solution is really nice and well done, thank you for it.

Answer (score 3):

As you are looking for specific elements inside the document, I suggest highly you locate them by using xpath:

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expression = sprintf('//todo[titel = "%s" and erstellt = "%s"]/erledigt', $_GET["titel"], $_GET["timestamp"]);
$result = $xp->query($expression);
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = 'Ja';
}
```

This results into the following (exemplary) xpath expression:

```
//todo[titel = "sasd" and erstellt = "2012-04-30 17:19:21"]/erledigt
```

Which will select all `erledigt` nodes that are part of a `todo` node that have the `titel` and `erstellt` node values as specified.

You can then easily change it. Additionally you're looking for `erledigt` nodes that aren't "erledigt" yet, but the current variant already doesn't hurt.

[Demo/Full Code Example](http://codepad.org/Dsby1NR4):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/10388661/367456
 */

$_GET["titel"] = 'sasd';
$_GET["timestamp"] = '2012-04-30 17:19:21';

$xml = '<todos>
  <todo>
    <titel>sasd</titel>
    <erstellt>2012-04-30 17:19:21</erstellt>
    <erledigen_bis>2012-05-03</erledigen_bis>
    <erledigt>Nein</erledigt>
    <thingstodo>sffsdfdf</thingstodo>
  </todo>
</todos>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expression = sprintf('//todo[titel = "%s" and erstellt = "%s"]/erledigt', $_GET["titel"], $_GET["timestamp"]);
$result = $xp->query($expression);
foreach ($result as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue = 'Ja';
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea introducing searching via XPath to someone who can't figure out which XML extension to use.

Comment: TS uses DOMDocument, so I opted for "that" xpath, it's equally simple with simple-xml which has xpath, too (and the same expression does simplify simplexml code, too).

Comment: I read something about XPath on my research the whole afternoon, but it was to complicated for me, because it is my first project with XML, PHP and JS, so I'm really on the beginning of my travel through web-development. But it was nice to see the solution with XPath, thank you for the interesting but also complicated stuff ;)

Comment: @alderos: You're welcome. There is always something to learn regardless if you've just started or already do this for years. ;)