# XML Search Value with Condition in PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, xml, search

let's say I got a **place_categories.xml** file as following, and this is pure xml file and is not retrieved from any database:

```
<category>
<pcid>23533</pcid>
<name>Designer Clothing Shop</name>
<sub_category>shopping</sub_category>
</category>

<category>
<pcid>23540</pcid>
<name>Dim Sum Restaurant</name>
<sub_category>food & drink</sub_category>
</category>
```

How to find such : Select name, sub_category where pcid=**23540** in **PHP and JQuery** and resulting

**Dim Sum Restaurant 

 food & drink**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this if you want to avoid XPath:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "place_categories.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function parseXml(xml)
        {
            //find every Tutorial and print the author
            $(xml).find("rootnode").each(function() {
                if($(this).find("pcid").text()==="23540") {
                    console.log($(this).find("sub_category").text());
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: thanks izb, but I'd prefer to avoid console.log, it looks nasty in IE

Comment: Yeah, that was just an example :) Presumably you'd use the data as you need to instead.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and XPath - but I have no clue what PHP has to have to do with that:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.get( "http://localhost/~gregory/place_categories.xml", 
        function( data ) {
            var name = data.find('/category[pcid = "23540"]/name');
        } );
} );
```

Sure XPath exists as well in PHP, and if you're looking for a similar example, see this yesterdays [answer to *Can't changing an xml value with PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10388894/367456).

Related:

- [Choose between XPath and jQuery with an XPath-jQuery phrase book](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xpathjquery/index.html?ca=drs-)

Comment: it looks promising, the reason why I should have both PHP and JQuery is browser compatibility, and in PHP to avoid bare xml url path

Comment: You can make the PHP script return the XML if that is what you're concerned about, but I would divide your problem and solve it step by step so you don't care about all problems at once but one after the other. That works much better.

Comment: Yes, I think this is close to what Im lookin for. I also find that PHP returning XML reduces the file. For eg. url:"primer-category.xml" -> 344KB
url: "primer-category.php" ->41KB if you do gzip in your php header content, but I can still find the xml file in html format inside my browser cache

Comment: @Gregory: Everything you transfer to the browser can be found in the one or other kind of cache later on. You probably want to only pass the one entry from the file over the wire. If so, do the xpath wihthin the php file and return the data as `json`.

Comment: and that's another thought I never think of...must be 4 hours sleep and loaded of caffeine. thanks..you're the man